# Highcharts - Bubblechart - adding padding to top and bottom of plot

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization, bubble-chart

I have created a bubble chart in Highcharts as follows:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moonspace/svcuLgso/)

As you can see the 'bubbles' for data '0' and data '7' are cut off.

Is there anyway to add padding on the top and bottom to take this into account ?

*I know extending the axis range to -1 -> 8 will sort this out but I'd rather not do it that way*

Here's the code:

```
$(function () {

    var data = [{ x: 0, y: 1, z: 1, dataSeries: 'data #1', dataPerc: '1.2' },
                { x: 1, y: 2, z: 2, dataSeries: 'data #2', dataPerc: '2.2' },
                { x: 2, y: 0, z: 0, dataSeries: 'data #3', dataPerc: '19.2' },
                { x: 3, y: 7, z: 7, dataSeries: 'data #4', dataPerc: '12.0' },
                { x: 4, y: 5, z: 5, dataSeries: 'data #5', dataPerc: '24' },
                { x: 5, y: 4, z: 4, dataSeries: 'data #6', dataPerc: '12' },
                { x: 6, y: 3, z: 3, dataSeries: 'data #7', dataPerc: '15.3' },
                { x: 7, y: 3, z: 3, dataSeries: 'data #8', dataPerc: '1.2' }];         

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
            credits: false,

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        title: {
            text: ''
        },

        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
           categories: ['data #1', 'data #2', 'data #3', 'data #4', 'data #5', 'data #6', 'data#7', 'data #8']
        },

        yAxis: {
            startOnTick: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 7,
            title: {
                text: 'Score'
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}'
            },
            maxPadding: 0.2
        },

        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            headerFormat: '<table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.dataSeries}</h3></th></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Score:</th><td>{point.y}</td></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Percentage:</th><td>{point.dataPerc}%</td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            followPointer: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{ data: data }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the answer to this in a Google search: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/highcharts/Example/Axis_Label/Hide_axis_first_label.htm.

This code example shows off attributes called `showFirstLabel` and `showLastLabel` that you can use in either the `xAxis` or `yAxis`. These should accomplish what you want by adding the extra space for the bubbles by increasing the range of your `yAxis` (to -1 through 8), but not showing those extra labels, as you requested in your question.

Here is where I applied them in your chart options ...

```
    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: true,
        min: -1,
        max: 8,
        showFirstLabel: false,
        showLastLabel: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Score'
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}'
        },
        maxPadding: 0.2
    },
```

... and here is the result:

[image]

You can review an updated version of your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/svcuLgso/7/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Genius - Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Two alternative ways to handle this:

**1)** Set `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` to `false`. Adjust  minPadding/maxPadding if desired.

```
yAxis: {
  startOnTick: false,
  endOnTick: false,
  minPadding: 0.025,
  maxPadding: 0.025
}
```

**Output:**

[image: screenshot1]

**Fiddle:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/svcuLgso/8/

**2)** Just don't set a `min` or `max`, and let the chart do what it does.

```
    yAxis: { }
```

**Fiddle:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/svcuLgso/9/